# How To Set Current User Identity Information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement login with discord. I have the user's discord information, now I need to make it so that they are authorized to view certain pages.

I've tried:

```cs
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name = User.id;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true;
```

However, this won't work because they are read only values.

Here is what the User class currently looks like:

```cs
public class User
    {
        public string id;
        public string username;
        public string discriminator;
        public string avatar;
        public bool verified;
        public string email;
        public int flags;
        public int premium_type;
    }
```

And I am checking to see if the ID exists in the database. Then I am trying to have this be the current logged in user for asp.net Identity.

How can I set this user as the current logged in Identity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the UserManager and SignInManager.

In your controller add these dependencies.

```
private readonly UserManager _userManager;
private readonly SignInManager _signInManager;

public AccountController(
    UserManager userManager,
    SignInManager signInManager)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

Then use those two managers to get the information you want

```
var appUser = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);
```

To get your application user

```
_signInManager.SignInAsync(appUser);
```

Then that user will be signed in, assuming they already exist in your system. If they do not you will need to create a new user through the _userManager.

Here is some reference links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn613290(v%3Dvs.108)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: What if I have 2 controllers? After verifying the user is in the DB, I would look to have use a [DiscordAuthorize] AuthorizeAttribute before each actionresult.

Comment: Would you mind getting in a discord chat to try to help me resolve this please?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to do that. If I were you I would research more into AspNetIdentity. Discord is not going to pass you full AspNetUsers, it will only pass you key user information, such as Username, Id, Email etc. Then it will be up to you to manage those roles and user information in your system independently of discord. Then if you create the user and they are logged in you can just have an authorize header on your controller, something like  `[Authorize(Roles = "DiscordUser")]`

Comment: I think your solution above is for Asp.Net Core? I've updated the tags, is there any way you could make it work for mvc? I'm not sure where in my controller I should put the above code.

Comment: Yes that is .Net Core code, the principles are the same but I am not sure where you would register your UserManager and SignInManager in AspNet 4.5 or prior. The principle should be the same maybe this link can help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: I can't seem to get that suggestion to work either. I keep getting an error when trying to use UserManager. "Using the generic type 'UserManager<TUser>' requres 1 type arguments. My code: var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);